# Show that if A is a square matrix and A^TA is nonsingular, then A is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $A$ is a square matrix and $A^TA$ is nonsingular, then $A$ is nonsingular. **Hint**: use the SVD.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Is there any part in particular that is giving you difficulty? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: The hint is a poor one: instead just prove the contrapositive.

Comment: how to prove it?

Comment: What kind of book would get as far as SVD while still dealing with such elementary facts?

Comment: @GitGud I hope it's from a problem set and not a published textbook...

Comment: @GitGud SVD can be proven with surprisingly little (I think one can prove SVD before the rank-nullity theorem, for example).  In certain fields, it is certainly much easier and more practical to think of transformations in terms of their SVD.

Comment: @Amber we understand that you don't know how to prove the statement.  However, we'd still like to hear your thoughts on the problem so far.  What have you tried that hasn't worked?  Have you tried writing out $A^TA$ in terms of the SVD of $A$?

Comment: @user7530 Search for *SVD* [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~ammann/stat6341.pdf), third (and last) entry.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Even so, this is as elementary as $Ax=\mathbf{0}\implies A^TAx=\mathbf{0}\implies x=\mathbf{0}$, for all column vectors $x$, this is just basic linear independence. I'll be in shock if the hint is actually good.

Comment: Thing is, I don't see how you prove this using SVD without needing this same result for the special case of $A$ diagonal. Which is no easier to prove than $A$ general...

Comment: @user7530 sure it is!  Diagonal matrices are invertible iff their diagonal entries are non-zero.  At any rate, it's easier to think of them in terms of their actual entries, rather than via norms or inner products.

Comment: @user7530 it depends on how you define singularity.  For all we know, the book defines singularity in terms of singular values, in which case showing that such an $x$ exists seems roundabout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to prove it. $$det(A^TA) = det(A^T)det(A) = (det(A))^2 \tag 1 $$ 
use the fact that a matrix is nonsingular if and only if its determinant is not zero.

$A^TA$ is nonsingular implies $det(A^TA) \neq 0.$ now bt $(1),$ we have $detA \neq 0,$ and that shows $A$ is nonsingular.

Comment: This way seems easier!

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $A$ and $A^T A$ have the same null space.  (Let's assume $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$.)

\begin{align*}
& Ax = 0 \\
\implies & A^T A x = 0 \\
\implies & x^T A^T A x = 0 \\
\implies & \| Ax \|_2^2 = 0 \\
\implies & Ax = 0.
\end{align*}

No need for the SVD.

Answer (score 3):

**Further hint towards the intended solution:**

Note that if $A$ has SVD $A = U\Sigma V^T$, then
$$
A^TA = U\Sigma^T\Sigma U^T
$$
Note that $U(\Sigma^T\Sigma) U^T$ is another SVD.  So, when is the matrix $A^TA$ non-singular?